# Fix AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'HTTP_201_CREATED'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have  implememented the following method on a viewset and I'm having an issue when posting I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'HTTP_201_CREATED'`. Why am I getting this error message since the `data` has already been serialized into json format.

```
def create(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
        # Payload Items 
        paid_to = request.data['paid_to']
        paid_from = request.data['paid_from']
        amount = request.data['amount']
        description = request.data['description']
        date = request.data['date']
        status = request.data['status']

        # System Item
        auth_= get_auth(request)
        # Limit currency choices if setup
        default_currency = DEFAULT_CURRENCY
        # Get Transaction Type & show cr and dr accounts involved:
        transaction_type = TransactionType.objects.get(id=request.data['transaction_type'])
        get_credit_account = transaction_type.credit_account
        get_debit_account = transaction_type.debit_account 

        # Money To Internal Value 
        amount_to = Money(amount,DEFAULT_CURRENCY)

        # Auto generate transaction number 
        transaction_number = increment_transaction_number()

        # Create Transaction objects 

        transaction = Transaction.objects.create(
            transaction_type=transaction_type,
            organization=auth_,
            paid_to=paid_to,
            paid_from=paid_from,
            description=description,
            date=date,
            amount=amount_to,
            transaction_number=transaction_number)
        trans_id = transaction.id
        # print(trans_id)
        # Add directions to legs  ..note positive direction is DEBIT and negative direction is CREDIT
        positive_direction = 1
        negative_direction = -1


        # Add leg objects instances to track debits and credits TODO can add mutiple legs

        Leg.objects.create(transaction=Transaction.objects.get(id=transaction.id), account=get_credit_account, description=transaction.description, amount=+amount_to * positive_direction)
        Leg.objects.create(transaction=Transaction.objects.get(id=transaction.id), account=get_debit_account, description=transaction.description, amount=-amount_to * negative_direction)

        serializer = CreateTransactionSerializer(transaction)

        from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
        data = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overriding `rest_framework.status` with this line:

`status = request.data['status']`

You need to rename this variable to something else in order to use

`status.HTTP_201_CREATED` from `rest_framework` library

Answer (score 2):

This error doesn't have anything to do with your serialization. It comes from the last line, where one of the parameters you send to Response is `status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED`. But `status` here is what you defined near the start of the method: `status = request.data['status']`. So it's a string, and doesn't have an attribute called that.

Clearly you meant to reference the `status` module you imported from `rest_framework` at the top of your module. But your string variable hides that. You need to change the name of your variable.

Comment: Fixed. I truly agree it  had nothing to do with the serialization. Next time I should be careful declaring variables that might conflict with `from rest_framework.response import Response` in built variables like `status`